# Can we use JS concat() inside Template literals (Template strings)?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, stringtemplate

I am trying to create a URL using Template Strings like -

```
a = {
    link: {
        pathname: `${url.split('?')[0]}${userId}/items?userType=${userId}}`
    },
};
```

The above snippet is working absolutely fine so is the below one.
But should we use concat() inside Template strings like the below snippet or not?

```
a = {
    link: {
        pathname: `${url
            .split('?')[0]
            .concat(`${userId}/items?userType=${userId}`)}`,
    },
};
```

Why I used concat() because in my case, my enabled linting setup is throwing error for the first one as it should be written in two-lines, but it takes a new line or space as we give, which is not favorable in our case as we are creating URL.

If not, why?
Just Curious.

Comment: No need to use a string template here, removing `\`${` and `}\`` from around the whole expression would lead to the same result.

Comment: Yes, you can use any kinds of operations and functions in a template literal interpolated expression, including `+` and `.concat()`, but it's just weird to put a static string in a template literal. What do you mean by "*not favorable*"?

Comment: Indeed; `\`${expression}\`` is just `expression` turned into a string; if `expression` is already a string, that's completely pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers for you:

1. The content of a substitution (`${...}`) can be **any** expression. It's fine to do method calls there.
2. `concat` seems like an odd choice in that particular case, since there's no need for it. For that reason, from a style perspective, I'd use the first version. But it's a style thing, and you *can* use `concat` if you like. Note [VLAZ's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114458/can-we-use-js-concat-inside-template-literals-template-strings/64114521#comment113376343_64114458) that once you've done that, the whole expression is already producing the string you want and you have no need of a template literal at all.

So I'd either use your original:

```
a = {
    link: {
        pathname: `${url.split('?')[0]}${userId}/items?userType=${userId}}`
    },
};
```

or if you prefer `concat`:

```
a = {
    link: {
        pathname: url
            .split('?')[0]
            .concat(`${userId}/items?userType=${userId}`)},
    },
};
```